# What does 'Isogeny is determined by its kernel up to automorphisms' mean?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, automorphism-group, arithmetic-geometry, isogeny

This is question from Silverman's *Advanced topics in the arithmetic of elliptic curves*, p. 106.  Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be elliptic curves.
What does

> isogeny $φ:E_1→E_2$ is determined by its kernel, at least up to an automorphism of $E_1$ and $E_2$

mean? Once $\text{ker}\, φ$ is given, what can we say about $φ$ and what does it have to do with $\text{Aut}(E_1)$ and $\text{Aut}(E_2)$ ? (To me, $\text{Aut}$ is nothing to do with $φ$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an analogue in group theory that is pretty arrow-theoretic (meaning it's about general nonsense with mappings that you see in many categories having quotients) and thus applies to modules, vector spaces, and so on.

Let $f  \colon G_1 \to G_2$ and $f' \colon G_1 \to G_2$ be surjective group homomorphisms between the *same* groups with the *same* kernel $K$. Are $f$ and $f'$ related? They induce isomorphisms $\overline{f}, \overline{f'} \colon G_1/K \to G_2$. Then $F = \overline{f} \circ \overline{f'}^{-1} \colon G_2 \to G_2$ is an *automorphism* of $G_2$ and $F \circ \overline{f'} = \overline{f}$ as isomorphisms $G_1/K \to G_2$, and pulling back to $G_1$ we get $F \circ f' = f$ as homomorphisms $G_1 \to G_2$.  Thus the homomorphisms $f$ and $f'$ with the same kernel are the "same" map up to an automorphism of $G_2$.

Comment: Hello, I really appreciated your online notes on (infinite) Galois theory. What does 'arrow-theoretic' mean? I have a good knowledge of many of the basics of category theory but have never seen this (presumably categorical) term

Comment: I updated my answer with a parenthetical description. I could have said "categorical" instead.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. I asked in case it referred to a specific discipline that I might want to learn more about